# C# Filter Data from Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase

I'm Working with [Firebase.Xamarin](https://github.com/jquaglio/Firebase.Xamarin) with my simple application C#

I have more Data in Firebase .. and maybe the data more than 100000 child

i need to search in this all data and get once of child's

Like the Filter

I have this Data:

```
"Images" : {
"-KywU04RZIbWVd5d5L2Z" : {
  "DateModels" : "11/15/2017",
  "No_Model" : "test",
  "id_user" : "BINHATHEEMALI",
  "imagePath" : "https://google.com"
},
"-KyyglTLexIZzIBLvSYO" : {
  "DateModels" : "11/15/2017",
  "No_Model" : "9825",
  "id_user" : "BINHATHEEMALI",
  "imagePath" : "https://facebook.com"
},
"-KyyhIiVpRLv9hNM_kYR" : {
  "DateModels" : "11/15/2017",
  "No_Model" : "HS887",
  "id_user" : "BINHATHEEMALI",
  "imagePath" : "https://bing.com"
},
```

I want search for once child by "No_Model" 
I'm finished C# code like this :

```
            var databaseURL = new FirebaseClient(Link);
        var Images = (await databaseURL.Child("Images")
          .OnceAsync<AddModelToFirbase>()).ToList();

        var nameUserUploaded = from iteem in Images where iteem.Object.No_Model == Model select iteem.Object.id_user;
        foreach (var name in nameUserUploaded)
        {
            string us = name.ToString();
            UserUploadedImages = us;
        }
        var Image = from item in Images where item.Object.No_Model == Model select item.Object.imagePath;
        foreach (var img in Image)
        {
            string IMG = img.ToString();
            return IMG;

        }
```

Above code is working. get all data and put it on List<>

if i have more data that make my app very slow

it's impossible to get data by searching by "**No_Model**" Only ?

Comment: have you tried `orderby`?

Comment: Like this : 
var database =new FirebaseClient(Link);
            var images = (await database.Child("Images")
                .OrderBy(Model).OnceAsync<AddModelToFirbase>()).ToList();

Comment: no OrderBy("No_Model")

Comment: Okay I'll try now. but how i can send the parameter I'm looking for?

Comment: equalTo("HS887")

Comment: Good. but i face error too ..
`  var database =new FirebaseClient(Link);
            var images = (await database.Child("Images")
                .OrderBy("No_Model").EqualTo(Model).OnceSingleAsync<AddModelToFirbase>());
            string test = images.imagePath; `

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Not Handle . because this Xamarin. , 
I'm remove Await from code : **
var database =new FirebaseClient(Link);
            var images =  database.Child("Images")
                .OrderBy("No_Model").EqualTo(Model).OnceSingleAsync<AddModelToFirbase>();
            string test = images.Result.imagePath; ** 

the error gone 
but the test variable is null .. and i'm sure the model no is founded